# Prevent service from starting manually when dependent services are down

Tags: upstart, services

Suppose I have two services `db` and `app` (which needs `db` to be up and running before it starts). They are starting correctly on startup and when I do `sudo service db stop` it stops both `db` and `app`.

But is there a way to get the following scneario to work? It is basically preventing one service from starting when the other is not available.

- `db` and `app` are up and running
- `app` is manually brought down to redeploy (`service app stop`)
- in the meantime `db` goes down from some reason
- calling `service start app` stops with unsatisfied dependencies (`db` not working)

I'm thinking about inspecting status of `db` service in `app` pre-start. But not sure whether it's the right way.

Comment: Upstart would look like wrong tool for the job, since it is event-based and not dependency-based. Your way seems to be the closest thing to the "right" way: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#block-another-job-until-yours-has-started